# Material skews and stretches when placed on a new object

Tags: modeling, materials

I created a galvanized texture. Worked great on one object. The next object I applied it to it stretched for some reason. I tried Cntrl A / Scale thinking that might reset the stretch but it did nothing. So here I am. I'm thinking a coordinates node or something?

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the question: you don't need the RGB to B&W node: instead of using the color information for the noise and voronoi use **Fac** (which is B&W information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Object Texture Coordinates with uniform scale

If a procedural texture has no input, by default it is mapped with **Generated Texture Coordinates** type which basically have a Z coordinate value of zero at the bottom face and 1 at the top faces.

As your object is tall, between the two faces there is a lot of space to be filled compared with the other object where the texture looks un-stretched.

To get rid of the dipandency from the geometry size I would suggest to use **Object Texture Coordinates**, which is based on the Origin location and Scale. Using a **uniform scale** for the object (e.g. 1,1,1, 0.2,0.2,0.2...or applying the scale with <kbd>Crlt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) will result in a isotropic texture mapping too.

Comment: I tried using Cntrl + A but that didn't work. I'll try Object Texture Coordinates. Where do I plug that in? At the beginning (left) of the node tree? And should it be the purple "Object" dot to the purple "Vector" dot?

Comment: You should both Apply scale & set Object Tex Coordinates. Yes, at the "beginning". Yes, exactly as you wrote. Obiuvsly should be done for all the procedurale texture of the nodetree.

Comment: Sorry, I did just as described: selected the object with the stretched materials problem, did a Cnrtl + A + Scale and then added "Object Texture Coordinates" at the beginning ---and there was no change. As seen here: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/Untitled-4.jpg

Comment: There are two procedural texture nodes in the setup: noise and voronoi. Both of them should have the object texture coordinates as their vector input. After that you'll probably have to adjuste their scale, to match the previous look.

Comment: Ahhhh. ok. It worked when I added "Object Texture Coordinates" to the Voronoi. Before I had only added Object Texture Coordinates to the Noise.. and in fact, it seems to have little or no effect when I messed around with the Object Texture Coordinates as connected to Noise. And of course now.. other problems have developed but I guess that's a story for posting anther question.... ha. Thanks.