# Texture on Each Side

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I placed a simple bump wave texture on my model but on the side faces it stretch:
[image]

this is the node setup:
[image]

Someone know how may i fix this problem an make the texture uniform all around the model?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try playing with an Object Texture Coordinates Node?

Comment: I found a similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44295/material-skews-and-stretches-when-placed-on-a-new-object/44301#44301

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Wave* texture is 3D, and you've chosen the *Bands* option.

If no Texture Coordinate is supplied, the texture will default to using the *Generated* texture space, which is (0,0,0) at the minimum XYZ of the shaded object's bounding box, and (1,1,1) at the maximum. The bands are parallel. Wood doesn't grow like that, so the bands need to be messed with quite a lot.

Another common approach to wood is:

**First find your log**

[image]

The log is mapped in its object space. The log's origin is at its center, with Z running along its length. The *Rings* version of the *Wave* texture is used, oriented and scaled so the growth rings are around the center, and stretched the other way, in Z.

[image]

In the bottom branch of the node tree on the left, a Voronoi texture muddles the texture space in a vaguely 'knotty' kind of way. There are probably better ways to do this, but the point is the main geometry, starting with the *Texture Coordinate* node.

**Then cut your planks**

Here are some planks using the log's object texture-space, and the same material as the log.

[image]

Of course, the log and its object space are only here to illustrate. In practice, you could use the plank's own object space, but shifted and rotated to offset the space in the same way as the planks are offset from the log. If you want the offset to be different for each plank, you can include some kind of random-per-object factor in the offset:

[image]

This is by no means exemplary wood: there are plenty of better (and more complex) examples out there, but I hope this is enough to show the principle. All these billets share the same material:

[image]

One fault with this is that Blender's *Wave > Rings* are actually spherical like an onion, not cylindrical: just stretching along Z is not great. To get cylindrically concentric rings with varying seasonal growth and wobble all the way down the imaginary log, I *think* you would have to make your own cylindrical-bands node group, but that's another question.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: Robin Bestt at it again :).

Comment: @JachymMichal I actually thought I might not have answered the question.. 'wood' isn't mentioned. In which case your answer is more appropriate..:)

Comment: Who cares about appropriate answers when I can learn so much from yours :).

Answer (score 4):

To avoid distorted textures and have better control you can use a UV map.
Then you can rotate different parts depending on your needs.

1. Create a UV map for your mesh
2. Connect it using the Texture Coordinate node
3. Manipulate it either directly or using the Mapping Node.

*Unwrap your Mesh. You can also move individual parts of your UV map.*

[image]

*Connect your UV map and use Mapping node to manipulate it*

[image]