# Why my text object looks wired in such material?

Tags: materials, uv, text-object

I have a brick material attach to my text object 
[image]

It looks normal in up view , but the side view looks weird , the brick become so horizontal , I set image texture project way to *Box*, and materials coordinate is *Object* method, but still don't know why.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I want it to turn smoothly and in a normal brick way, the two face edge should have a smooth materials.

Comment: there's something wrong with your projection, check the UV map.

Comment: Maybe you should edit manually that section in the UV Editor

Comment: Hello :). This similar question could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170089/78972