# Create painted wood with grain

Tags: materials

I need a material that looks like painted wood in Blender 2.83.

I have attached an image that shows the colour and grain. Any ideas with Shader Editor would be grtefully accepted.

Cheers[image: Red door]

Comment: Hi. Please show what you have tried and where, *specifically*, you are getting stuck. Thanks.

Comment: I made a very similar procedural wood in answer to a question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173195/35559).. and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559) you will have to supply your own world HDR, or use one of the previews, to stop it appearing magenta.. I didn't pack that in the .blendfile

Answer (score 1):

[image: Simple Shader]
I usually start with a Wave Texture set to ring. Since the door is made from many parts, it should be uv unwrapped to reflect that, or copies of the material made per board so the grains can be different. The position of the ring, and scale, is set using the mapping node, and the output fed to a color ramp, which feeds roughness in the principled BSDF. The original ring output can also be used to control a second noise texture to add the lines.

Comment: As @robinbetts points out in his [excellent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170089/texture-on-each-side/170172#170172) it would be better to use geometry space rather than UV unwrapping, especially if you want the grain to go around a corner.