# Easy render of CLT (Cross Laminated Timber)?

Tags: rendering

I'm interested in learning how to create a material that would do a "decent" representation of Cross Laminated Timber. Typically, these are mostly rectangular shapes with simple cutouts and other features used in constructing floors, walls, and roofs of Mass Timber type buildings. I'm not necessarily interested in photorealistic, but something that would reasonably represent grain direction on the top of the panels and the cross laminations visible on the end grain. Any ideas?

[image: CLT panel]

Comment: Some variation on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559) ? Do you want to model the slabs as single cuboids, or make them up of planks?

Comment: I'm more interested to model as cuboids. Example above is 4" thick, so I'd model a panel that would be 4" thick. Just not sure oh how to material the edges and top/bottom.