# Noise texture is not oriented correctly

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

In the image below, you can see my box has the wood texture (modified noise texture) oriented correctly in the front side (the side with a white rectangle on it). But on the other side, it looks like a splash of ink, while I want it all to be the same as the front side orientation (all sides should be even with texture regardless of their size or direction).
[image]

My nodes:
[image]

**Note: I've tried UV unwarp, and Smart UV project, but they did nothing.**

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: maybe bring the Mapping scale values back to 1?

Comment: You aren't using UV coordinates, you're using object coordinates. Change the output of your texture coordinates node.

Comment: Smart UV Project is a tool to automatically UV unwrap a mesh: They are not separate. Make sure you fully understand UV maps and unwrapping, then try again.

Comment: Depending on your application, you may be able to follow the rule to 'make separate parts _as_ separate parts' .. do a bit of joinery, and use a texture like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559)