# Unwrapping a beveled cube for minimal seams? For seamless textures?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm looking to see if there is a common / correct way of unwrapping a beveled cube for a seamless texture, specifically a wood texture.

[image]

I can of course mark seams where the flat faces used to be (now the flat + chamfers) and rearrange / rotate these groups manually, but this is tedious and there will always be more than one place where the seam is visible (below).

[image]

Is there a common way of unwrapping a beveled cube (or other object) that results in minimal seams?

Comment: Strictly, to capture the  grain of solid wood seen in the round (as opposed to a veneer), you really need to generate [some kind of  3D texture,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559) which you can bake for a seamless result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For objects like this you will always have visible seams when using a stock texture with UV projection.

If all you want is a simple seamless look and you don't care about full realism, box mapping may do the trick - it uses triplanar projection, which is a common shortcut for getting seamless looks for simple textures without using any UV map.

[image: Node Setup for Box Mapping]

For a realistic look you would either need several different image textures and a painted mask, or a procedural material as Robin mentioned in their comment - not just because of the seams, but also because grain on cut wood will flow differently on different sides of the cube as seen here:

[image: photo of wooden cubes from pixabay]