# Wood Material/Texture Extrudes unevenly on mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, extrude

What I did,

- created a handle for a frying pan with curve.
- Gave curve depth and converted curve to mesh
- Extruded and scaled one end of the handle so it closes up.
- Added a wood material/texture to mesh
- Looked good until getting to the extruded end of the mesh: the wood material had streched.

How I tried to correct it:

- Removed wood material completely, applied All Transformation, and Append the wood material once again, still the same.
- Went to edit mode > World tool > Settings > Options: Toggle Transform (Correct Face Attributes), still the same.

Reference images 
[image]

[image]

[image]

What can I do to correct it?

Comment: Did you add a seam, and UV unwrap it?

Comment: @JohnEason Nothing of such, but I added a Sub-surf Modifier and it seemed better.

Comment: It's never going to look exactly right If you think about it because the end of the handle will show the end grain of the wood, whereas your material is presumably just a straight 'plank'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John Eason has commented, a UV texture will never simulate the surface of a wooden pan-handle, unless baked from 3D. They are turned from a solid piece, not veneered.

Following the principles [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559), you can, instead, make 3D procedural wood, and carve your handle out of it:

[image]

.. you would need to adjust this to scale, depending on the size of your model. The noise and distortions interact quite a lot, so I won't deny systematically tweaking can be quite a job. It remains a project to develop a procedural wood with more independent components.. that would probably mean abandoning the *Wave* texture altogether, and working more from the bottom up.

Anyway, this one flows OK across the piece:

[image]

[image]

.. and can stand variations in lighting:

[image]

I hope you might find it tweak-able enough to suit.

[image]