# How can I make musgrave texture more uniform along my model?

Tags: texturing, uv, shader-nodes

I am trying to make a wood material, but I am having some trouble to make my noise texture to be uniform.

This is my nodes.

[image]

This is the visualization:

[image]

As you can see the musgrave texture is weird in these parts.

I tried to use UV Coordinates, but my my model is circular and I coulnd't make it.

[image]

Is there a way to make this noise texture more uniform?

Comment: Procedural wood grain more typically simulates growth rings, and carves out of the log: see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559) and maybe [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298560/35559). For a  more sophisticated approach, I rate  [Lance Phan's  turorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7e0vxgBS8A)